# Why am I not able to view the components inside JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{   
    GUI()
    { 
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JLabel L_Name = new JLabel("Name");
        JLabel L_Roll = new JLabel("Roll no");
        JLabel L_Year = new JLabel("Year");
        JLabel L_Branch = new JLabel("Branch");
        JLabel L_Marks = new JLabel("Aggr Marks");

        JTextField T_Name = new JTextField(15);
        JTextField T_Roll = new JTextField(15);
        JTextField T_Year = new JTextField(15);
        JTextField T_Branch = new JTextField(15);
        JTextField T_Marks = new JTextField(15);

        JLabel R_Name = new JLabel("");
        JLabel R_Roll = new JLabel("");
        JLabel R_Year = new JLabel("");
        JLabel R_Branch = new JLabel("");
        JLabel R_Marks = new JLabel("");
        JLabel R_aggr = new JLabel("");

        JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6,3,7,7));

        p1.add(L_Name);
        p1.add(T_Name);
        p1.add(R_Name);

        p1.add(L_Roll);
        p1.add(T_Roll);
        p1.add(R_Roll);

        p1.add(L_Year);
        p1.add(T_Year);
        p1.add(R_Year);

        p1.add(L_Branch);
        p1.add(T_Branch);
        p1.add(R_Branch);

        p1.add(L_Marks);
        p1.add(T_Marks);
        p1.add(R_Marks);

        p1.add(R_aggr);
                                                         
        submit.addActionListener(this);
                                                         
        p1.add(submit);
                                                             
        frame.add(p1);                                                                   
        frame.setLayout(null);                                                               
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);                                                               
        frame.setSize(300,330);                                                                      
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);                                                                
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {

    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
            GUI g = new GUI();
    }
}
```

I've added the `JPanel` to the `JFrame`, it is still not visible.

I am not getting any errors

#### This is what I am trying to do:

> Create a GUI to enter the details of a student on the left side of the window. The following details are required: Name, Roll number, Branch (use radio button), Year (drop down list) and Aggregate marks. On clicking a submit button the consolidated details along with the total marks should be printed on the right side of the GUI (Use Swing and frame).

Comment: Why are you indenting code all over the place? Code that is in the same block and code that is on the same level needs to have the same indentation.

Answer (score 4):

You're shooting yourself in the foot with this line:

```
frame.setLayout(null);
```

When you do this, you the programmer are completely responsible for specifying all the sizes and positions of components added to the container. While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.

So don't do this but instead use the layout managers and let them do the work for you.

Also as a side recommendation, I recommend that you try to improve the formatting of your code that you post in here and your code in general. Good formatting including using an indentation style that is uniform and consistent will help others (**us**!) to better understand your code, and more importantly, it will help **you** to better understand your code and thus fix your own bugs. Also it shows that you're willing to put in extra effort to make it easier for the volunteers here to help you, and that effort is **much** appreciated.

e.g., your code should look like this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    GUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JLabel L_Name = new JLabel("Name");
        JLabel L_Roll = new JLabel("Roll no");
        JLabel L_Year = new JLabel("Year");
        JLabel L_Branch = new JLabel("Branch");
        JLabel L_Marks = new JLabel("Aggr Marks");

        JTextField T_Name = new JTextField(15);
        JTextField T_Roll = new JTextField(15);
        JTextField T_Year = new JTextField(15);
        JTextField T_Branch = new JTextField(15);
        JTextField T_Marks = new JTextField(15);

        JLabel R_Name = new JLabel("");
        JLabel R_Roll = new JLabel("");
        JLabel R_Year = new JLabel("");
        JLabel R_Branch = new JLabel("");
        JLabel R_Marks = new JLabel("");
        JLabel R_aggr = new JLabel("");

        JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6, 3, 7, 7));

        p1.add(L_Name);
        p1.add(T_Name);
        p1.add(R_Name);

        p1.add(L_Roll);
        p1.add(T_Roll);
        p1.add(R_Roll);

        p1.add(L_Year);
        p1.add(T_Year);
        p1.add(R_Year);

        p1.add(L_Branch);
        p1.add(T_Branch);
        p1.add(R_Branch);

        p1.add(L_Marks);
        p1.add(T_Marks);
        p1.add(R_Marks);

        p1.add(R_aggr);

        submit.addActionListener(this);

        p1.add(submit);

        frame.add(p1);
        // frame.setLayout(null);  // *** Get rid of
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        // frame.setSize(300, 330); // *** Get rid of

        frame.pack(); // **** add

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        GUI g = new GUI();
    }
}
```

Comment: but i've tried using BorderLayout also, still the same trouble

Comment: @AmalKK: contentPanes already use BorderLayout. Note changes to your code above -- now the JPanel is seen. Don't forget to call `pack()` on the JFrame and don't set its size. Also note how to correctly indent code. If we can't read your code, we can't understand it and then can't help you.